# Footer is not centering text

Tags: html, css

My footer won't center text while another div with the same class(in my case called "container")works perfectly. [As you can see the "Lorem Ipsum" works just fine while "Footer stuff" text is mostly on the right side of the box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSopX.png) I have tried giving it its own class and trying around some stuff like putting putting the text-align left but that was still at an awkward offset of the middle.

Here's my code:

```css
Body {
    background-color: darkred;     
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li {
    float: left;
}
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%; /* BE ADVISED! (????) */
}
#ipsumpic1 {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
}
#ipsumpic2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebarleft {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: -350px;
}
#sidebarright {
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: -537px;
    margin-right: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Prachtige website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type=text/javascript src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" width="200"></a>
            </div>
        </header>
            <ul id="navbar"> 
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="producten.html">Producten</a></li>
                <li><a href="diensten.html">Diensten</a></li>
                <li><a href="over.html">Over Ons</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <main>
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <img id="ipsumpic1" src="img/ipsum1.svg">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a pulvinar dolor, a rutrum tortor. Vestibulum auctor finibus odio id efficitur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur ullamcorper risus neque, sed vehicula augue finibus sed. Donec pretium ornare libero a venenatis. Donec sed ex id tellus posuere interdum. Nullam tincidunt egestas odio non gravida. Sed ut felis aliquet eros commodo elementum. Aliquam ullamcorper, diam quis aliquet tempor, magna nisi laoreet nisl, at vestibulum arcu enim quis elit. </p>
                <img id="ipsumpic2" src="img/ipsum2.svg">
                <p>Ut faucibus dui lectus, vitae pharetra magna maximus quis. Donec sollicitudin sem non ornare vulputate. Suspendisse pretium lacus nec gravida tristique. Sed sed nibh et eros facilisis accumsan. Nam mi elit, fermentum eu laoreet vel, venenatis sit amet leo. Curabitur erat arcu, dictum eu massa quis, hendrerit mattis turpis. Etiam ultrices quam dolor, a interdum erat eleifend eu. Cras sed blandit nunc. In dictum dignissim enim, vel gravida nisl sagittis pellentesque. Quisque fermentum pellentesque velit a faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In fermentum, mi id feugiat ultricies, nulla lorem elementum felis, et pretium velit mauris sit amet odio. Curabitur facilisis, mi in eleifend commodo, enim ex dignissim quam, ut pulvinar magna nisl et orci. Duis pulvinar imperdiet pretium. Nullam vehicula tortor in ex volutpat egestas. </p>
            </main>
            <div id="sidebarleft">
                <aside>
                    <h2>Nieuw nieuws!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin. </p>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarright">
                <aside>
                    <h2>Social media!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin.</p>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Footer stuff</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit faucibus libero quis lacinia. In in varius tortor. Donec nec finibus sapien. Curabitur tincidunt at quam vel commodo. In ut suscipit metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent dictum justo ut odio consectetur consectetur. </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please someone help me on this one, I've got no idea how to fix this one.
  
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to the `.container` to clear the `float`'s:

```css
body {
  background-color: darkred;     
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li {
  float: left;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 160px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%; /* BE ADVISED! (????) */
  clear: both; /* added */
}
#ipsumpic1 {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}
#ipsumpic2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#sidebarleft {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 1000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: -350px;
}
#sidebarright {
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 240px;
  float: right;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: -537px;
  margin-right: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" width="200"></a>
  </div>
</header>
<ul id="navbar"> 
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="producten.html">Producten</a></li>
  <li><a href="diensten.html">Diensten</a></li>
  <li><a href="over.html">Over Ons</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <img id="ipsumpic1" src="img/ipsum1.svg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a pulvinar dolor, a rutrum tortor. Vestibulum auctor finibus odio id efficitur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur ullamcorper risus neque, sed vehicula augue finibus sed. Donec pretium ornare libero a venenatis. Donec sed ex id tellus posuere interdum. Nullam tincidunt egestas odio non gravida. Sed ut felis aliquet eros commodo elementum. Aliquam ullamcorper, diam quis aliquet tempor, magna nisi laoreet nisl, at vestibulum arcu enim quis elit.</p>
    <img id="ipsumpic2" src="img/ipsum2.svg">
    <p>Ut faucibus dui lectus, vitae pharetra magna maximus quis. Donec sollicitudin sem non ornare vulputate. Suspendisse pretium lacus nec gravida tristique. Sed sed nibh et eros facilisis accumsan. Nam mi elit, fermentum eu laoreet vel, venenatis sit amet leo. Curabitur erat arcu, dictum eu massa quis, hendrerit mattis turpis. Etiam ultrices quam dolor, a interdum erat eleifend eu. Cras sed blandit nunc. In dictum dignissim enim, vel gravida nisl sagittis pellentesque. Quisque fermentum pellentesque velit a faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In fermentum, mi id feugiat ultricies, nulla lorem elementum felis, et pretium velit mauris sit amet odio. Curabitur facilisis, mi in eleifend commodo, enim ex dignissim quam, ut pulvinar magna nisl et orci. Duis pulvinar imperdiet pretium. Nullam vehicula tortor in ex volutpat egestas.</p>
  </main>
  <div id="sidebarleft">
    <aside>
      <h2>Nieuw nieuws!</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin.</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebarright">
    <aside>
      <h2>Social media!</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin.</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Footer stuff</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit faucibus libero quis lacinia. In in varius tortor. Donec nec finibus sapien. Curabitur tincidunt at quam vel commodo. In ut suscipit metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent dictum justo ut odio consectetur consectetur.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

it's working on align center